# How can I use PowerShell to get RAM / Memory details of multiple computers?

Tags: powershell, csv, ram

I need to inventory the RAM of the computers that are listed in a text file. I have this script:

```
$($servers = Get-Content D:\123.txt

Foreach ($s in $servers) {
    $s
    get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $s -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| select Name | Format-List
    Get-WmiObject win32_baseboard -ComputerName $s -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Select product | Format-List

    $colRAM = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computerName $s

    $colRAM | ForEach {
           “Memory Installed: ” + $_.DeviceLocator
           “Memory Size: ” + ($_.Capacity / 1GB) + ” GB”       
           $SlotsFilled = $SlotsFilled + 1
           $TotMemPopulated = $TotMemPopulated + ($_.Capacity / 1GB)
    }

    Write-Host "_____________________________________ "
}) *>&1 > output.txt
```

Which returns this result:

> computer1
>
> Name : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8500  @ 3.16GHz
>
> product : DG31PR
>
> Memory Installed: J6H2 Memory Size: 1 GB

I would like the result to be like this and exported to CSV:

```
Name      TotalRam      Type      Motherboard
comp1     2gb           ddr3      h81m-k
comp2     2gb           ddr3      h81m-k
          2gb
comp3     1gb           ddr2      DG31PR
          0,5gb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modified version of your script to get the result you requested.

```
#For more types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(v=vs.85).aspx
$memtype = @{
    0 = 'Unknown'
    1 = 'Other'
    2 = 'DRAM'
    20 = 'DDR'
    21 = 'DDR-2'
    22= 'DDR2 FB-DIMM'
    24 = 'DDR3'
    25 = 'FBD2'
}

$Result = @()

$servers = Get-Content D:\123.txt


Foreach ($s in $servers) {

    $Motherboard = (Get-WmiObject win32_baseboard -ComputerName $s -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).product 
    $colRAM = Get-WmiObject -Class "win32_PhysicalMemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computerName $s

    $TotMemPopulated = 0
    $SlotsFilled = 0

    $colRAM | ForEach-Object {
        $SlotsFilled = $SlotsFilled + 1
        $TotMemPopulated = $TotMemPopulated + ($_.Capacity / 1GB)  

        $Props =[ordered]@{        
            Name = $s
            TotalRam = "$TotMemPopulated`gb"
            Type = $memtype[[int]$_.MemoryType]
            MotherBoard = $Motherboard
        }
        $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $Props

    }

    $Result += $Object
}

$Result | Export-CSV RamReport.csv
```

**Explanation:**

`$memtype` is a hashtable that converts the numeric `MemoryType` number from the `win32_PhysicalMemory` WMI class to the friendly name. You may need to add more references to this hashtable depending on the variety of RAM in your environment (I have provided a link to the numeric code references).

`$result` is defined as an empty array, which is used during the script to collate the results in to an object.

The script creates an object as `$object` with a hashtable of the properties you wished to collate and then adds each object to the $result collection. This is an ordered hashtable so that we respect the column order that you requested in the final output.

Finally we export `$result` to CSV using `Export-CSV`.

Comment: works great! but can we define quantity of ram, for example 2x1gb?

Comment: You could add this to $props : `NumberOfDimms = $colRAM.Count` which would get you a count of how many dimms, but it won't tell you the exact sizes of them. To be sure about that (as they could be mismatched) you'd need to record the size of each dimm individually.