# powershell listing Ram information

Tags: powershell, server, ram

I am trying to find out what type of RAM is in a computer. I'd like to know whether the modules are UDIMM, RDIMM, LRDIMM or any other type. This would be very useful so I can plan what modules are going into what servers at the data center.

This is what I have so far:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory |
        Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceLocator, Manufacturer, PartNumber, 
        @{ label = "Size/GB"; expression = { $_.Capacity / 1GB } },
        Speed, Datawidth, TotalWidth |
        Format-Table -AutoSize
```

This is useful information but I'd like a column that tells me the type (UDIMM, RDIMM, LRDIMM) and a way to list the DIMMS that are empty as it will make it easier to see what DIMM is full/empty (but this isn't a huge problem).

this is not a duplicate as i am looking for the type of Ram that is stored on the servers so i know what Ram to buy and put in without having to travel a long way to find out i got the wrong type

Comment: I answered a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43092016/2796058

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use PowerShell to get RAM / Memory details of multiple computers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091085/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-get-ram-memory-details-of-multiple-computers)

Comment: no duplication, i am mainly looking at showing the RAM type if its IDIMM, RDIMM ect so it makes it easier what ram i will need to put in the servers without travelling miles and miles and finding out i have got the wrong type

Comment: There's this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882767/how-to-retrieve-memory-type-rdimm-or-udimm

Comment: again how does that answer my question about the type of Ram in a server?

Answer (score 1):

The [Win32_PhysicalMemory class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(v=vs.85).aspx) contains a reference for translating the `MemoryType` value to the type of memory module. Turn it into a hashtable for easy access:

```
$MemoryTypeMap = @{
    "0" = 'Unknown'
    "1" = 'Other'
    "2" = 'DRAM'
    "3" = 'Synchronous DRAM'
    "4" = 'Cache DRAM'
    "5" = 'EDO'
    "6" = 'EDRAM'
    "7" = 'VRAM'
    "8" = 'SRAM'
    "9" = 'RAM'
    "10" = 'ROM'
    "11" = 'Flash'
    "12" = 'EEPROM'
    "13" = 'FEPROM'
    "14" = 'EPROM'
    "15" = 'CDRAM'
    "16" = '3DRAM'
    "17" = 'SDRAM'
    "18" = 'SGRAM'
    "19" = 'RDRAM'
    "20" = 'DDR'
    "21" = 'DDR2'
    "22" = 'DDR2 FB-DIMM'
    "24" = 'DDR3'
    "25" = 'FBD2'
}

Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory |Select @{Label = 'Type';Expression = {$MemoryTypeMap["$($_.MemoryType)"]}}
```

Comment: This works well but tested on the local computer and both saying unknown which doesn't get me anywhere :(

Comment: Well, if Windows doesn't know then there's not much you can do without looking up the part in vendor documentation

Comment: When I run @MathiasR.Jessen 's suggestion, it reports back DDR3 for my computer.  You should try this on your production PCs, some may report back the answer, some may not.  For those that don't you'll have to manually research which part number equals which type of RAM, and between my answer and his, you're well on the way to success :)

Comment: Next entry of your array:     "26" = 'DDR4'

Answer (score 0):

You can see which memory devices are in which slots by using the WMI class of `CIM_PhyicalMemoryArray` and `CIM_MemoryDeviceLocation`.  I've used WBEMTest and `Get-CimInstance`, however, and it doesn't seem that Windows reports on which memory slots are open on the motherboard.

My best guess?  You'll need to use the `Win32_Baseboard` class to report on the model of the motherboard, and do some legwork manually to see how many slots each model has.  You can then use the data from `CIM_MemoryDeviceLocation` to determine how many slots are open.

An approach to do so might look like this.

```
$memorySlots = Get-CimInstance Win32_MemoryDeviceLocation
$motherBoard = Get-CimInstance win32_baseboard

switch ($motherBoard.Product){
    #find the motherboard models for the most common models and populate manually w/ count of ram slots 
    "0TM99H" {$Totalslots = 2}
    Default {$Totalslots = 4}
}

 Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory |
        Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceLocator, Manufacturer, PartNumber, 
        @{ label = "Size/GB"; expression = { $_.Capacity / 1GB } },
        Speed, Datawidth, TotalWidth, @{ label ="FreeSlots";exp={$Totalslots-$memorySlots.Count}}
```

It would look something like this:

```
PSComputerName : SLVER
DeviceLocator  : DIMM A
Manufacturer   : Elpida
PartNumber     : 8KTS51264HDZ-1G6E1
Size/GB        : 4
Speed          : 1600
Datawidth      : 64
TotalWidth     : 64
FreeSlots      : 0

PSComputerName : SLVER
DeviceLocator  : DIMM B
Manufacturer   : Elpida
PartNumber     : 8KTS51264HDZ-1G6E1
Size/GB        : 4
Speed          : 1600
Datawidth      : 64
TotalWidth     : 64
FreeSlots      : 0
```

Finally, you asked about memory type present, that also doesn't seem to be info that we know of, from a WMI perspective.  Or rather, if WMI does know about it, I couldn't find it anywhere.

I think you'll need to do some manual work too there, gathering the memory part number, then manually research to determine what type of RAM it is, then finally add that info to the output by adding another Switch statement, as shown.

```
switch ($memorySpecs.PartNumber){
    "8KTS51264HDZ-1G6E1" {$RAMType='SoDimm'}
    Default {$RAMType="Unknown, research $($memorySpecs.PartNumber)"}
}
```

#### Update

Mathias provided an excellent method to look up RAM if the BIOS on that PC reports it to Windows.  I've tested on a few systems, some report their RAM Type while others don't.  For those that don't, you can reference the partNumber property as I've demoed above to manually look it up.  After a few iterations, you should be able to gather the data and program your own exceptions, and wrap up this task.